# How can I atomically (or at least properly) create User in the system with multiple bounded contexts?

Tags: domain-driven-design, modeling, bounded-contexts

I need to register user in the system. User cannot exist without a Role (and he surely cannot exist without login and password). Administrator is supposed to be able to add new users by selecting role, writing login/password and some user information. Login/password/security concerns are implemented as separate application/BC (authentication context), roles and permissions are in authorization context and user information is in separate account management context. How can I implement user registration process if all these contexts could be in theory deployed on separate machines? For now I'm using application interface that uses infrastructure service implementation to synchronously and atomically send all needed commands to different BCs (currently it is the same big application).

[image: Картинка]

Comment: Is you question "how to integrate all those services"?

Comment: Kind of. It's "how to register a user?". If I send registration command to one of the bounded contexts, User aggregate root from this context will raise an event that will propagate throughout some bus and eventually make all bounded contexts consistent. But to be able to do so, I need to create some kind of integration context that will have a user registration command with all needed data for all those contexts... and I need to somehow store state, etc. Lots of overcomplication emerges, I just want a simple architectural answer.

Comment: "Atomically" and "multiple bounded contexts" are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Communicating between two Bounded Contexts in DDD](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16713041/communicating-between-two-bounded-contexts-in-ddd)

Comment: Can you choose a solution from the given answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *may* be that you have gone down to a too fine degree of granularity with your bounded contexts.  An indication of this is usually when the concept you are referring is the *exact same* thing in more than one bounded context.

Things like `User` management (registration / authentication / authorization) is typically handled by an **Identity & Access Control** Bounded Context.

That `User` would have different meanings / concepts in your downstream bounded contexts: e.g. Author, Supervisor, etc.

However, if you are sure that you want that level of granularity then you are going to have to pick a *system of record* for your user and *that* bounded context would own the user and be responsible for the process manager state and seeing the registration through to completion; although, I usually like to have my process management as a bounded context in and of itself and *it* can orchestrate among the others.

As for doing so atomically... I don't know whether this would necessarily be wise to attempt :)

Answer (score 2):

**A simple architectural answer**: Use a `Saga` (or a `Process Manager`) that orchestrates all this.

You have an architecture that consists on three microservices. There are two stiles to integrate microservices: [Orchestration and Choreography](https://medium.com/@varjoinen/orchestration-vs-choreography-9cec9e137910#.tqha6hrer). A `Saga` uses orchestration.

Read more on SO about the [differences between them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127241/orchestration-vs-choreography).

*Update:* 
I think that `Account management` should be the master BC. Here the user   is born, initially without a role or a meaning to authenticate. Then, it is given a role, a purpose and after that, after it is setup, a username and a pasword. This should be the sequence.

Comment: Where will this `Saga` live? Should I create `Integration bounded context` that will define this Saga and related Command? (in other words, who should be responsible for starting the Saga? User should be able to fill in all needed fields in UI)

Comment: In which bounded context  is this entity first created? The commands need to reach an `Aggregate` first, not a `Saga`; a `Saga` only listen for `events` and generate/dispatch new `commands`, it does not handle `commands`. So, think where you do send the first `command`. Where do this `Saga` lives depends on your microservices distributions. I think it could live anywhere as long as it can listen to all relevant `events` and can dispatch orchestration `commands`.

Comment: That's what I am trying to find out. User cannot be registered without a role (business rule), but at the same time nor can he be registered without username/password (especially considering security concerns, where if we register user in Authorization Context first, we'll need to store password somewhere (and send it in commands/events through the wire unhashed).

Comment: You should hash the passwords as soon as possible, i.e. before the command executes.

Comment: I think that `Account management` should be the master BC. Here the user   is born, initially without a role or a meaning to authenticate. Then, it is given a role, a purpose and after that, after it is setup, a username and a pasword. This should be the sequence.

Comment: So, `Account management` BC should be aware about `userName`, `passwordHash` and `role` concepts even though they are not present in the `User` aggregate root in `Account management` BC? Or maybe `User` aggregate root in `Account management` BC should contain those fields?

Comment: No. A `Saga` should know how to create all the relevant Commands. But a Saga does not strictly belong to a single BC. It connects them.

Comment: But `Saga` should be instaniated by event, so event raised by `Account management` context should contain all the relevant data needed in order to create `User` in all other BCs...

Comment: I never did this but you could send a composite command to a `Saga`

Answer (score 0):

You'd need a distributed transaction server for that. Java has a standard for distributed transactions (JTA).