# Term choreography in openshift Vs Container Orchestration in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

In any Container Orchestration engine (kubernetes or openshift), there are steps to be carried out, starting from designing the pipeline to pull the source code, create the Docker images, define the configuration to deploy the application and expose it.

Then, why is the term "choreography" is used in Openshift([reference](https://blog.openshift.com/beyond-container-orchestration-paas-choreography/)) and term "Container Orchestration" is used in Kubernetes. What difference does it make?

Comment: Do you have any more references? I haven't seen the term before but in this case  the author seems to relate "choreography" to a higher level abstraction of pulling everything in a platform together rather than container orchestration specifically. For example a lot of environments would have developers committing, triggering tests, triggering builds, triggering deploys, monitoring, dashboards, self service etc. I think they are trying to say that container orchestration is only one component to the overall choreography of a platform.

Comment: @Matt - No I do not have any other references. I found this link to see the difference between orchestration and choreography https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127241/orchestration-vs-choreography

Comment: I see this question doesnot require any research effort. In this devops world, lot of jorgan words are used inappropriately which needs clarity. Similar question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127241/orchestration-vs-choreography) has many wonderful answers to differentiate the terms. I was expecting what makes openshift different for the author to say as choreography. what features or internals work differently in openshift?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenShift as a Kubernetes fork and vendor is free to invent whatever new terminology they want for marketing purposes. None of these terms have formal definitions in the first place, but even without that marketing is its own domain and rarely bound by such things. My guess is their marketing team thinks "choreography" conjures a feeling of overall poise and balance? Which the think aligns with their brand in some way.

tl;dr it's advertising, not technical terms.