# Microservice architecture design question

Tags: microservices

**Assume that I use rest call to communicate in all parts**

I found that most microservice architect is like below:
[image]

If there is a request need all of these services to compute the result.
The request path like below:
**client-> Account Service -> Inventory Service  ->Shipping Service**

The path is long and complex.
If there is error occur after Account Service, I need to do compensation by Saga pattern.

I want to ask that can I add a logic unit "A" on top of those services like below:
[image]

So that I can process all logic on this service. Those service only help the logic unit to query and phase the raw data. All complex logic do in the logic unit.

Answer (score 0):

*can I add a logic unit "A" on top of those services*

You *can* do anything you want to. Whether you should do it or not is up to you. There are no rules that state that microservices should not call each other, though popular opinion guides you to try to avoid it where possible.

The decision you are facing is what is known as the "orchestration vs choreography" trade-off. You should read up on this before making your decision.

[Orchestration vs. Choreography](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127241/orchestration-vs-choreography)

> Service orchestration represents a single centralized executable
> business process (the orchestrator) that coordinates the interaction
> among different services. The orchestrator is responsible for invoking
> and combining the services.
>
> Service choreography is a global description of the participating
> services, which is defined by exchange of messages, rules of
> interaction and agreements between two or more endpoints. Choreography
> employs a decentralized approach for service composition.

Comment: Thank you for your answering. I think this site <https://www.softobiz.com/microservice-orchestration-vs-choreography/> explains Orchestration vs. Choreography very well too.